# CE 1.8 - attribute with 2 values display in additional information

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute, additional-information

I am working on Ceramic website, and my Client want to display the Technical details of their products. The challenge is that each Technical specification has 2 values, additional information tab would displayed in 3 columns.

e.g.

```
Characteristics    Standard Value   KIT Value
```

---

```
1) Dimension       + 0.5 %          + 0. %
```

---

```
2) Thickness       + 0.6 mm         + 0.2 mm
```

---

How do I create attribute and publish in product detail page in additional information tab? Or any other way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered this problem before and found that creating a list with a comma or better a pipe (|) separating each item.

When you go to display your info on the frontend you can explode the list and format it anyway you want.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

But its difficult for my client to add a pipe/comma between 2 values, as they wont understand and except such manual intervention.

Is it not possible to add attribute columns?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using EAV so you could add attributes like this:
dimensional_standard
dimensional_kit
thickness_standard
thickness_kit